# html pattern attribute

Tags: html, regex, attributes

I'm trying to limit my text input to only allow letters, not numbers. With a maximum of 100 characters. I'm having trouble finding out how to use the pattern attribute to only allow letters. Here is a portion of my code attempting this.

```
<form action="http://www.severien.com/grit/formecho.php" method="post" target="_blank">
        <label for="videorequests"> Video Requests:</label>
        <input type="text" id="videorequests" name="videorequests" maxlength="100" pattern="[a-z]{1,100}" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton" />
    </form>
```

Using the attribute maxlength I'm limiting the character input to 100. How do I use pattern to limit the character use to only letters, excluding numerical characters?

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
pattern="[A-Z a-z]{1,100}"
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the value [^@]+@[^@]+\. represents. but when I input the value pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,100}" It wont allow any spaces within the text box.

Comment: Try this: pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{1,100}" @DanielNease

Comment: I believe I have figured it out. There needs to be a spaces in between [a-z A-Z]

Comment: @DanielNease The difference between `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{1,100}` and `[a-zA-Z ]{1,100}` is that the first one doesn't allow the value to start with a space, while the second one does. (Also, the first one allows up to 101 characters to be typed.)